# Do not list groups in regex output

Tags: php, regex, capture

```
> preg_match_all("/<td colspan=\"3\">(.-?){5,}<\/td>/", $input_lines,
> $output_array);
```

So this is my preg_match code to get my desired values. But as an output I got
group names which I don't want to have. I want to put groups in Array 0 or remove them at all. Because I am printing the last match but I get group name instead of my desired output.

This is the output:

```
0   =>  array(17
0   =>  <td colspan="3">Lucifer-Pilot.HDTV.x264-LOL <br>Lucifer.S01E00.Pilot.720p.HDTV.x264-TOPKEK</td>
1   =>  <td colspan="3">Lucifer.S01.HDTV.x264 | 720p.HDTV.x264</td>
1   =>  array(17
0   =>  K
1   =>  4
```

When I use     `> echo end($matches[1]);` It prints 4.

When I remove groups using ?:     `> echo end($matches[1]);` this doesn't work.

Desired output is:

```
<td colspan="3">Lucifer.S01.HDTV.x264 | 720p.HDTV.x264</td>
```

Which is the last of the matches.

Comment: would need to see the input and the desire output

Comment: I added the desired and normal output

Comment: I think you must take the time to well understand how: - `preg_match_all` displays the results (take a look to the PREG_SET_ORDER option at the same time). - capture groups are numbered. - behaves a repeated capture group. What you are trying to do isn't very difficult, however the trusted way to extract data from html is to use DOMDocument and DOMXPath.

Comment: I can't do it with dom parser so I have to go with preg_match :/